# Run multiple classes sequentially in testng.xml

Tags: xml, testng

I am trying to run multiple classes one after the other using `testng.xml`, but the tests are running in parallel.  I don't want them to run in parallel.  My `testng.xml` looks like this:

```
<suite thread-count="1" name="Test Sample Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="aia Pod" preserve-order="true" annotations="JDK"> 
    <parameter name="url" value="some url"></parameter>
    <parameter name="username" value="XAIA/user"></parameter>
    <parameter name="password" value="passwd"></parameter>  
    <classes> 
      <class name="classA"/>
      <class name="classB"/>
    </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Running this XML opens two browsers at the same time.  I want class A to run first and then open a new browser and run class B once A is completed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `parallel=false` at the suite level to achieve this.

It might help if you refer to [this](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running) to understand how parallelism works using an XML.